# Puppet 3.7 Parameter path failed

Tags: puppet

I wanted to update Puppet from 2.7 to 3.7.
Currently I run two Ubuntu 14 VMs, one as puppet master and one as agent.
The setup works just fine and now I want to fix all bugs and other deprecated features caused by the upgrade, however the following error has me baffled.

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter path failed on File[/]: File paths must be fully qualified, not ''

Even though I used -debug and -verbose I didn't get much more information than that.
I guess the problem is that sometimes a variable I have inside a File[$variable] can be empty?

But how am I supposed to know which manifest is causing the problem? I have too many to check them all out.

Comment: Consider using validate_absolute_path: (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#validate_absolute_path) from puppet stdlib. It will help you verify puppet parameters.

Comment: Are you actually trying to manage the filesystem root?  Because that's what Puppet seems to think.  This could be a sign that some variable is not being defined, or at least, not as soon as you need it.

Comment: Good points, I'll check it out next week when I'm at work again. I'll stay in touch.